# image looks different in ios simulator than in photo preview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, ios-simulator

I've got a somewhat weird problem. I wanted to set a background image for a `UITableView`, but I also wanted to apply specific `UIImageView` methods on it, so I created a `UIImageView` underneath the `UItableView` and set the background color of the `UITableView` to `[UIColor clearColor]`. However, when I'm viewing my image in the simulator, the image looks a bit darker than in the imagepreviewer on mac. How is this possible?

For referenence, here is a screenshot that indicates the difference: http://cl.ly/image/2L0S18273m3O

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to add a view behind the tableView as `UITableView` has a [backgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW57) property that you should set instead.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = ({
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your-image"]];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly made my code more efficient. However, it doesn't change the fact that my image looks weird on the simulator..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
Setting your UIImageView as a subview of your table view (in storyboard drag image view onto tableview), then setting the background colour of the table view to be white => colours in simulator and storyboard are the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't work. Setting it as the subview causes the tableviewcells to move.. Btw: I've got 2 sorts of uitableviewcell, so it might work if i had one.